# Recover data from a Windows Dynamic Volume Spanned Disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, dynamic-disk

I have a dynamic volume created with two spanned partitions over two disk. Recently, one disk has started failing, and I want to copy the data inside that disk to another disk, before replacing it.

However I don't know how to select only what is inside the failing disk, because the partitions spans across both disks.

Would imaging the entire disk do the work? Or do I have to copy all the data from both disks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy just the data in one disk...it is all over both disks. You will have to treat them as one disk, and copy all the data off. Image the disk ASAP, because if one actually fails, your situation just became 100 times harder.

Comment: I will try imaging both disk as if they were one unique disk.

Comment: @iCe If it turns out to be broken, you can buy professional version of File Scavenger ($185) that can recover files from broken volumes or RAID arrays. http://www.quetek.com/prod02.htm It is an awesome tool...I recovered the data off a broken RAID 5 array once with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use live CD on your RAM. Search for Windows XP mini, download it and write it to a CD. Boot the OS from CD and then you can access the disk as normal and copy the content you want.

Comment: Using Hirens Boot CD, still the disk appears as a dynamic volume, so it's using both disk. As said by KCotreau,  I can't access one disk only.